# How to initialize data correctly in vue js?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

It takes the initTableData and initTableFiltered after onChangeDistrict which i hope to not take it now, instead to take only the initTableFiltered

```
data () {
  return {
    data: []
  }
},
created () {
  this.initTableData()
},
methods() {
  initTableData () {
  db.collection('example').orderBy('owner_name', 'asc').get().then(res => {
    res.forEach((doc) => {
      this.data.push({
        id: doc.id,
      })
    })
  })
},
initTableFiltered () {
  db.collection('filter').orderBy('name', 'asc').get().then(res => {
    res.forEach((doc) => {
      this.data.push({
        id: doc.id,
      })
    })
}
onChangeDistrict () {
  this.initTablefiltered()
}
}
```

So how to initialize the initTablefiltered freshly on onChangeDistrict?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create data variable? This isn't in the code?
Ex:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: []
    }
  },
 ...
```

Without instantiate your data, this is not reactive...